# Elasticsearch and Tire to exclude deleted_at objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

i'm trying to exclude objects which are deleted.. deleted_at is a datetime field and if the object is deleted it has a timestamp otherwise its nil.

this is my code:

```
tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 2) do
  query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
  filter :missing, field: :deleted_at
end
```

but this does exactly nothing on my output..

any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are basically 3 states that a field/property could be in.

1. It doesn't exist in the document.
2. It does exist and the value is set to be `null`
3. It does exist and the value is something valid (or non-null)

If I understand correctly you want docs where `deleted_at` is in state 1 or 2. I think you need to create the equivalent of this:

```
"filter" : {
    "missing" : { 
        "field" : "deleted_at",
        "existence" : true,
        "null_value" : true
    }
}
```

The inner missing filter will find all docs which are in state 1 (`existence: true`) or state 2 (`null_value: true`).

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your quick reply! i only want objects which are NOT deleted which means deleted_at IS NULL..

Comment: sorry for replying that late. it doesnt make any difference with this filter or not.. really weird. the deleted_at is a datetime field in the db.. do i have to specify something special?

Comment: Can you use a curl statement `curl -XGET 'http://local:9200/your_index/your_type/doc_id'` and see what exactly is stored in the `deleted_at` field of both a valid and deleted document?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? Was my answer helpful at all?

Comment: sorry for the delay. really weird. changed the server environment and it worked. THANKS!